# Python PuLP constraint . "eye"

Tags: python, constraints, pulp

I am a beginner in Python, working with PuLP.

My system uses time steps (as I am working with Renewable Energies), and I need to include a battery in the system. Therefore I need a constraint that allows me to collect energy in it.

My question here is, how can I write a constraint with variables that change values each time step (the state of charge of the battery, for instance). In mathlab I could use the function "eye", but here un PuLP I don't see how they use matrixes.

Any help would be very well appreciated.

Here is part of the code I have, which is not correct.

```
prob+= 63.128*CPV + 88.167*CWT + 126.97 * CBatt, "TotalCostSystem"

for i in idx:
    SOCB = SOCB + xBin - xBout 
    prob += SOCB <= CBatt
    prob += SOCB >= 0
    prob += xBout >= 0 
    prob += xBin >= 0
    prob += (CPV*cfPV['output'][i] + CWT*cfWT ['output'][i]) + xBout - xBin >= 0
    prob += (CPV*cfPV['output'][i] + CWT*cfWT ['output'][i]) + xBout - xBin <= 250



prob += lpSum(CPV*cfPV['output'][i] + CWT*cfWT ['output'][i] + xBout - xBin for i in idx) >= 5000
```

Thank you in advance

Priscila

Comment: I've answered this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47441934/python-pulp-beginner-constraint-lists probably best to remove this duplicate question.